# Send push notification if user is not active in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, push-notification

I would like to add a feature to my social app, which can send a push notification to a specific user, is he's not active.

For exemple, if the user has not logged in for 7 days: I would like to send him a push notification "Hey, it's been a while since you've logged in! Come see the new posts".

I know how to send a push notification to a specific user (that's not the problem), but I don't know how to create an automatic function which is able to know if the user didn't logged in for 7 days.

Do you know if it is possible ?

Ps: I'm using Firebase.

Comment: I think you can have a field something like `lastActiveTime`, and if difference between `current time` and `lastActiveTime` is more than 7days then you can send push notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use local notification here which is good solution I guess.

Whenever user open's the app schedule the local notification of after 7 days from current date. ( Make sure to remove previously schedule notification before adding new one. )

In this case if user open the app notification will reschedule automatically else notification will fire based on last schedule of it.

I did this way in one app and it worked as I explained.

Comment: Indeed, it was that simple aha !

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature can be executed on the Front-end side. All you need is about Local Notifications. When the user opens the app, you will create a local notification for next 7 days and delete the old one in case user open the app within 7 days.

Comment: A simple and efficient solution but it will not work if the user logs in from another device. Guess it's up to the OP to determine if this is important or not.